# Decimal Precision on Calculated Value

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to set a decimal precision to 2 places on a calculated value that I am posting in a label on Trading View. The problem is that there is no documentation on how to do this that I have been able to find. I have tried googling the issue as well and the implementations all seem not to exist anymore and throw errors in the console.

[image]

```
//@version=4
range = high - low
lpt1 = "\nPT1: " + tostring(high + (2*range))
label.new(bar_index[0], na,lpt1, color=color.black, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

I have tried round() and a few other things from various sources. Any insight on this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's documentation for that in `tostring()` function. `format` - that's you are looking for https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_tostring

So the code would look like:

```
//@version=4
study("Value precision", overlay=true)
m = 1.234567
str = tostring(m, "#.##")
label.new(bar_index, high, str)
```

and the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was it! Not sure how I missed that.